# Spring boot 1.5.6 + Force to compile thymeleaf files on every restart

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm using Spring boot 1.5.6 with Thymeleaf 3. As you know, every time when i restart the app, on first request for specific page, thymeleaf compile the response. Can i force spring boot to compile every template with the start, not with the first request.

PS: for production use. :)